# A question about grouped push notifications in the background (FCM)

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Can I send grouped push notifications in the background? like this [image].   Based on my knowledge about front programming (mobile app), background cannot control with front so I have to group in the back side (server). This means I have to send push notifications from the back side grouping push notifications so that mobile can get push notifications grouped like the image I uploaded above. Are there additional options when I send notifications? Below is my code to send push messages to my device.[image]

Comment: One app can have multiple notification channels.

Comment: what do you mean by multiple notification channels? do you mean this has to control in the app side(front)?